# Keras: Custom loss function without any mean

Tags: keras, neural-network, loss-function

Different loss functions used by default in Keras, make use of average beetween all sample and all components. In particular, I used:

```
model_cnn_dense.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=opt)
```

With this I obtain apparently good results 1 cm of error of mea in my regression test, but looking at the data, the maximum absolute error in my sequence of data is about 20 cm, that is not good for my application.

There is a way to not take the mean of absolute error for all samples, but simply to take the maximum absolute error for all samples?

Thank you very much!

---

Added Example (Edit):

I want to obtain from the NN the values:

1,2,3
...
4,5,6

The reconstruction from the NN is:

1,2,6
...
4,5,6

So the mae obtained is:

```
(ABS(1-1)+ABS(2-2)+ABS(3-6)+...+ABS(4-4)+ABS(5-5)+ABS(6-6))/N
```

If N is just composed by the six shown elements, the final mae is 0.5 (really low value)

What I want to obtain is instead a loss function which do not give me the mean absolute error, but the maximum absolute error:

```
MAX(ABS(1-1),ABS(2-2),ABS(3-6), ..., ABS(4-4)+ABS(5-5)+ABS(6-6))
```

If N is just composed by the six shown elements, the final maximum absolute value is 3 (really different from 0.5)

This is my ideal loss function.

Comment: Can you add some more details about what exactly you want?

Comment: I edited the question, with a simple example

Comment: You can do that but then the loss function won't be representative of the entire batch. It will just represent one sample and the derivative would be with respect to that sample alone.

Comment: Umm, no. I just want the maximum abosulte error over all samples, instead of mean absolute error over all samples, so it will be representative of all N elements. I edited the question. Sorry if I was not clear.